# How to sort a file list according their part of the file name?

Tags: perl, sorting

I have an array(`@pssm_list`) which contains files like this

```
1.nr.pssm
2.nr.pssm
3.nr.pssm
4.nr.pssm
5.nr.pssm
6.nr.pssm
7.nr.pssm
```

the name of file list is `1.nr.pssm` to `226.nr.pssm`

I try to use `sort(@pssm_list)` , but the order is not from 1 to 226

so I try to write the code like this

```
opendir(pssm_handle,$ARGV[0]);
@pssm_list = grep(/\.pssm/,readdir(pssm_handle));

$tag = 0;
until($tag > 226)
{
        foreach $file (@pssm_list)
        {
                @Temp = split("[.]",$file);
                if($Temp[0] == $tag)
                {
                        push(@Sorted,join("",$file));
                }
        }
        $tag++;
}
```

I want to know does there exists any solution can sort the list in one line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I hit upon this problem as well, and I used this package called [Sort::Naturally](http://search.cpan.org/~bingos/Sort-Naturally-1.03/lib/Sort/Naturally.pm) to help me sort the numbers correctly.

> Under natural sorting, numeric substrings are compared numerically, and other word-characters are compared lexically.

Answer (score 3):

I think this should do it:

```
@Sorted = sort { int( $a ) <=> int( $b ) } @pssm_list;
```

This relies on the forgiving nature of `int()` whereby e.g. `int( "99xyz" ) == 99`.

If your filenames were more complex, you should replace `int( $a )` with a function call that extracts the numeric part, or use `map` as suggested by mpapec.

Edit: My first attempt was way off, sorry, been working in Ruby far too long to remember the correct Perl syntax!

Comment: ruby needs explicit `$a` and `$b`, and that seems to be only difference

Comment: @mpapec: In Ruby, you would generally do `pssm_list.sort_by { |item| item.method }`, and item.method would return an enumerable object with well-defined sort behaviour. Yes, it is also possible to use Perl-like syntax, but I haven't seen that much.

Answer (score 3):

```
my @pssm_list = 
  map $_->[0],
  sort { $a->[1] <=> $b->[1] }
  map [ $_, /(\d+)/ ],
  grep(/\.pssm/,readdir(pssm_handle));
```

or slightly less efficient sort:

```
my @pssm_list =
  sort { 
    my ($x,$y) = map /(\d+)/, ($a,$b); 
    $x <=> $y;
  }
  grep(/\.pssm/,readdir(pssm_handle));
```